# Parameterizing (potentially non-planar) equilateral polygons in 3d

Tags: geometry, 3d

This is similar to [Parameterizing equilateral polygons](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214874/parameterizing-equilateral-polygons) but for 3 dimensions.

I have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ ($n \geq 3$), labeled $1$, $2$, ..., $n$. Point $1$ is unit distance from point $2$, which is unit distance from point $3$, ..., and point $n$ is unit distance from both point $n-1$ and point $1$. WLOG, I set point $1$ to be the origin and point $n$ to be $(1, 0, 0)$ by translating and rotating my set of points as necessary.

This gives me a set of $n - 1$ conditions (one for each pair of numbering-adjacent points other than $1$ and $n$) on a set of $3(n - 2)$ variables, namely the coordinates for the $n-2$ points $2$ through $n - 1$.

Based on what I know about how many variables a single equation can/will eliminate, this should require less than $3(n-2)$ parameters to specify a group of these points, but cannot possibly take less than $3(n - 2) - (n - 1) = 2n - 5$ parameters. How many parameters do I actually need (in other words, how many degrees of freedom does this system have) and how do I retrieve the points from a given set of parameters?

Improved upper or lower bounds on the number of degrees of freedom, or values for special cases which might otherwise deviate from a general pattern, would also be appreciated. So far I know the following values:

```
 n | degrees of freedom
---+--------------------
 3 | 1
 4 | 3
 5 | 5
 6 | 7
```

but these each seem to have relatively independent ways of obtaining the points from a parameter set which I cannot see a way to generalize to more points.

Comment: This [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51893330_The_configuration_space_of_equilateral_and_equiangular_hexagons) deals with the 3D case.

Comment: That is helpful, but it seems to only address hexagons ($n = 6$). Is there a way to generalize it to more/less edges?

Comment: If you consider polygons modulo rigid motions then the space of polygons is a complex variety of complex  dimension $n-3$. It has very mild (isolated) singularities if $n$ is even and is a manifold if $n$ is odd. Quite a bit is known about topology of this space.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for that information! Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with complex varieties; if you have any references for me on this topic I would really appreciate it. This sounds promising; if I am understanding the implication correctly this would mean that the lower bound of $2n - 5$ degrees of freedom I obtained intuitively is exact. Is that correct?

Comment: Right. I will add a proper answer with references later on. What is your background? Do you know any differential or algebraic topology?

Comment: I have taken a graduate-level differentiable manifolds course and am currently in the middle of its successor course, algebraic topology (taught from Hatcher's standard book on the topic).